# Module 'tensorflow.python.platform.flags' has no attribute 'trace'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am getting this error. What does it mean? I am new to tensorflow and python. Please let me know how to correct this.

This is the error:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "main.py", line 299, in
> <module>
>     app.run()   File "/home/kbdp5524/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/platform/app.py",
> line 40, in run
>     _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)   File
> "/home/kbdp5524/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/absl/app.py",
> line 299, in run
>     _run_main(main, args)   File "/home/kbdp5524/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/absl/app.py",
> line 250, in _run_main
>     sys.exit(main(argv))   File "main.py", line 86, in main
>     if flags.trace == "": AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.platform.flags' has no attribute 'trace'
```

This is the code where I am getting the error:

```
    import tensorflow as tf
    from tensorflow.python.platform import app
    from tensorflow.python.platform import flags
    from monodepth_dataloader import MonodepthDataloader
    from models import *
    from utils import *
    from eval.evaluate_flow import load_gt_flow_kitti
    from eval.evaluate_mask import load_gt_mask
    from loss_utils import average_gradients
    from test import test
    '''
   def main(unused_argv):
    if flags.trace == "":
        raise Exception("OUT_DIR must be specified")

    print ('Constructing models and inputs.')

    if flags.mode == "depthflow":  # stage 3: train depth and flow together
        Model = Model_depthflow
        Model_eval = Model_eval_depthflow

        opt.eval_flow = True
        opt.eval_depth = True
        opt.eval_mask = True
    elif flags.mode == "depth":  # stage 2: train depth
        Model = Model_depth
        Model_eval = Model_eval_depth

        opt.eval_flow = True
        opt.eval_depth = True
        opt.eval_mask = False
    elif flags.mode == "flow":  # stage 1: train flow
        Model = Model_flow
        Model_eval = Model_eval_flow

        opt.eval_flow = True
        opt.eval_depth = False
        opt.eval_mask = False
    elif flags.mode == "stereo":
        Model = Model_stereo
        Model_eval = Model_eval_stereo

        opt.eval_flow = False
        opt.eval_depth = True
        opt.eval_mask = False
    else:
        raise "mode must be one of flow, depth, depthflow or stereo"

    with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.device('/cpu:0'):
        global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)
        train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(flags.learning_rate)

        tower_grads = []

        image1, image_r, image2, image2_r, proj_cam2pix, proj_pix2cam = MonodepthDataloader(
            flags).data_batch
       '''
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run()
```

The above is the part of the code where I think is causing the error. I am using Tensorflow 1.15 version. Please let me know how to do this.

Thanks very much :)

Comment: Can you share the complete code (if possible) so that we can try to help you. Thanks!